# What low-level wizard/cleric spells can create permanent difficult terrain?

Tags: spells, dnd-3.5e, terrain

Which low-level (1st-3rd) Wizard or Cleric spells can create long-lasting<sup>1</sup> difficult terrain in at least 6x6 squares? (Or 4 square radius)

It is to prevent Huge enemies from taking 5-foot steps.
Difficult terrain is preferred as darkness imposes a miss chance on attacks *against* the creature, and it can succeed on a save against blindness.

---

1) longer than 1 minute/level, preferably instananeous

Comment: Could you please expand on why a spell you request should be permanent? Do spells with reasonably long durations also count?

Comment: @annoyingimp if it is instantaneous, it cannot be dispelled. 10 minutes/lvl should suffice however

Comment: @András While *instantaneous* difficult terrain cannot be dispelled, *permanent* difficult terrain can be.  I recommend you change the operative word to 'long-lasting'.

Comment: Druids/Earth/Ranger have it easier: [SoftenEarthAndStone](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/softenEarthAndStone.htm), [SpikedGrowth](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/spikeGrowth.htm), [PlantGrowth](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/plantGrowth.htm) (using Overgrowth) eventually in combination with each other

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The 3rd level sorcerer/wizard spell *shatterfloor* from the *Spell Compendium* has an instantaneous duration and generates up to a 15-foot radius spread of difficult terrain at medium range.

No other spell on any spell list generates difficult terrain by name with an instantaneous duration except the 7th level druid-only spell *wrack earth* from the *Player's Handbook II*, as far as I can tell.  There are several low-level spells with a 1 min/level duration, though, and there're always caltrops.

Answer (score 5):

After combing through all the books I have to agree with The Dark Wanderer, the only spell that lists difficult terrain by name that is Instantaneous is *Shatterfloor* from the *Spell Compendium*.

That being said there is a second Instantaneous spell that **might** provide what you are looking for if you word/describe right and the terrain is rock/stone.  The *Stone Shape* spell from the *Player's Handbook* states that you can mold up to a 10 cubic foot + 1 cubic foot per level of rock into any rough shape.  It is a Cleric 3 spell.

In the 1 minute/level class I found only one that might provide movement hindrance.  In the *Complete Divine* book there is a Cleric 3 spell called *Briar Web* with a 20-ft radius that hinders movement.

Under the 1 round/level class I found several spells that hindered movement as well, not as long lasting but something to think upon for perhaps modifying/creating your own spell(provided your DM allows) that can help.  They range in Area from 5-ft square/level to 10-ft cubes to 20-ft radius.  From *Player's Handbook* the basic *Grease* spell(Wiz 1) and *Sleet Storm*(Wiz 3). From *Player's Handbook II* - *Scattering Trap*(Wiz 3) and *Vertigo Field*(Wiz 3). And finally from *Spell Compendium* - *Cloud of Bewilderment*(Wiz 2) and *Shadow Binding*(Wiz 3).

Sorry I couldn't find anything better but hopefully these will provide some ideas that you can work with.